# Flex 4 DateChooser

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, highlight, days, datechooser

I have an Array of days. I want those days to have a different background-color in the DateChooser component, say red.

How can I do that please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DateChooser isn't that easy to customise!

Something close to this will work, though you'll need to tweak it somewhat to suit what you want to do.

```
public class FancyDateChooser extends DateChooser {
    public var fancyStyleName : String;
    public var dayToMakeFancy : String;

    protected override createChildren() : void {
        super.createChildren();
        var dateGrid : UIComponent = mx_internal::dateGrid;
        for ( var i: int = 0; i < dateGrid.numChidren; i++ ) {
            if ( ( dateGrid.getChildAt( i ) as IUITextField ).text == dayToMakeFancy ) {
                dateGrid.getChildAt( i ).styleName = fancyStyleName;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Gregor. That will do. I was hoping I wouldn't have to extend the class, but it seems I can't get away without. I wonder if a custom skin will suffice though.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for Gregor Kiddie's share. I modified Gregor Kiddie's code a bit. Let it can input multiple dates.

```
public class MyDateChooser extends DateChooser
{
    public var highlightColor : Number = 0xff0000; // sample
    public var highlightDate : Array = ["10","20"]; // sample

    public function MyDateChooser()
    {
        super();
    }

    protected override function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {
        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        var dateGrid : UIComponent = mx_internal::dateGrid;
        for ( var i: int = 0; i < dateGrid.numChildren; i++ ) {
            if (dateGrid.getChildAt( i ) is IUITextField) {
                var textField:UITextField = dateGrid.getChildAt(i) as UITextField;
                for (var j:int = 0; j<highlightDate.length; j++) {
                    if ( textField.text == highlightDate[j] ) {
                        textField.textColor = highlightColor;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [disabledRanges](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DateChooser.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#disabledRanges) and [disabledColor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DateChooser.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#top). Here is an [example](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/05/04/setting-a-minimum-and-maximum-allowable-year-in-the-datechooser-control-in-flex/) on "Flex examples".

Comment: But I don't want to disable them, I want them usable, just marked up. Plus there's 2 or 3 colors I want to use.

Comment: Oops, I was asleep at the switch.