# Set datechooser "event" based on "if"

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, flex4.6, datechooser

I have a `dateChooser` in an app I'm working on; the app is to submit time cards.

I'm trying to figure out a way to set a color based on number of hours submitted -- i.e. red for less than 8, green for 8 exactly, yellow for more than 8. I already have the number of hours for that day being pulled from quick base as a number. Is there anyway set it to something like

```
if (hoursDateSelected <= 7){
   calendar.something = green
}
```

Comment: Maybe I am just not reading it right, but what object are you trying to set the color on? Is hoursDateSelected where you have already figured the number of hours? I think you are on the right track but without more code/explanation I cant be sure.

Comment: On the dateChooser, hoursDateSelected is the # hrs

Comment: So what exactly on the dateChooser are you trying to change the color of? The selected day? The current day? A date range? We are almost there.

Comment: On the dates based on the if, I have an arrayCollection that has the date and the number of hours. so the colors would be on individual days in the current month.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for:

[Flex 4 DateChooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813216/flex-4-datechooser)

Basically it is extending the component.